# FreeNas & Windows permissions

Tags: active-directory, truenas

I'm considering deploying FreeNas on a stand alone server, with aprox 3tb of storage space, to act as a file server.

Is it possible to create folders on this and assign windows permissions to them. For example:

\IT\
- And assign the "IT" group access rights to it in Active Directory

Answer (score -2):

I would take a look at OpenFiler instead.  It plays nicer with AD.

Comment: Thats not what was asked. That seems to be the SF "standard" answer to ANY FreeNAS related question